# Current time in microseconds in java

Tags: java, timestamp

On a Unix system, is there a way to get a timestamp with microsecond level accuracy in Java? Something like C's `gettimeofday` function.

Comment: Keep in mind that computer clocks are not set to anywhere near that level of accuracy - two clocks on different computers are usually going to differ by at least a few milliseconds, unless you've put some effort into setting up a high-accuracy synchronization procedure (when such a thing is even physically possible). I can't imagine what point there would be to knowing the computer's time to the microsecond. (If you're trying to measure an _interval_ that precisely on one computer, then sure, that's perfectly reasonable, but you don't need the full timestamp.)

Comment: Also, some versions of Unix/Linux only return 1 millisecond or 10 millisecond granularity in the microsecond field.

Comment: An indirect way is through [JDBC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), if connected to a database such as Postgres that captures current time in microseconds.

Comment: Java 9 and later: `Instant.now()`

Comment: Use Instant to compute microseconds since Epoch:

`val instant = Instant.now();`
`val currentTimeMicros = instant.getEpochSecond() * 1000_000 + instant.getNano() / 1000;`

Answer (score 160, accepted):

No, Java doesn't have that ability.

It does have System.nanoTime(), but that just gives an offset from some previously known time. So whilst you can't take the absolute number from this, you can use it to measure nanosecond (or higher) precision.

Note that the JavaDoc says that whilst this provides nanosecond precision, that doesn't mean nanosecond accuracy. So take some suitably large modulus of the return value.

Comment: One would conjecture that the reasons Java has no getTimeInMicroseconds() include 1) accuracy not available on many platforms, 2) returning millisecond accuracy in a microsecond call leads to application portability issues.

Comment: On Linux, System.nanoTime() calls clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,_). [Brian Oxley](http://binkley.blogspot.com/2010/10/java-aint-got-no-rhythm-but-can-it-keep.html) dug into Java's source code to find this nugget.

Comment: Is there a way to use clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,_) yourself in your java code?

Comment: It would be good to write what's the difference between precision and accuracy.

Comment: This Answer is **now outdated**. The OpenJDK and Oracle implementations of Java 9 come with a new implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) that provides for capturing the current moment with a resolution finer than milliseconds. On a MacBook Pro Retina I am getting the current time in microseconds (six digits of decimal fraction). Actual results and accuracy depend on the underlying clock hardware of the host computer.

Comment: @BasilBourque a lot of systems still run on Java 8 or even earlier since there's no need to migrate them. While the answer is outdated, it's still useful.

Comment: @Dragas Actually, there *would* be a need to migrate them… to get the current time in microseconds as asked by this Question.

Answer (score 114):

## tl;dr

Java 9 and later: Up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution when capturing the current moment. That’s 9 digits of decimal fraction.

```
Instant.now()
```

> 2017-12-23T12:34:56.123456789Z

To limit to [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
Instant                // Represent a moment in UTC. 
.now()                 // Capture the current moment. Returns a `Instant` object. 
.truncatedTo(          // Lop off the finer part of this moment. 
    ChronoUnit.MICROS  // Granularity to which we are truncating. 
)                      // Returns another `Instant` object rather than changing the original, per the immutable objects pattern.
```

> 2017-12-23T12:34:56.123456Z

In practice, you will see only microseconds captured with `.now` as contemporary conventional computer hardware clocks are not accurate in [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

## Details

The other Answers are somewhat outdated as of Java 8.

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. These new classes supplant the flawed troublesome date-time classes shipped with the earliest versions of Java such as java.util.Date/.Calendar and java.text.SimpleDateFormat. The framework is defined by JSR 310, inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project.

The classes in java.time resolve to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), much finer than the [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) used by both the old date-time classes and by Joda-Time. And finer than the [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) asked in the Question.

[image]

### `Clock` Implementation

While the java.time classes support data representing values in nanoseconds, the classes do not yet *generate* values in nanoseconds. The `now()` methods use the same old clock implementation as the old date-time classes, [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--). We have the new `Clock` interface in java.time but the implementation for that interface is the same old milliseconds clock.

So you could format the textual representation of the result of `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )` to see nine digits of a fractional second but only the first three digits will have numbers like this:

> `2017-12-23T12:34:56.789000000Z`

#### New Clock In Java 9

The OpenJDK and Oracle implementations of Java 9 have a new default `Clock` implementation with finer granularity, up to the full nanosecond capability of the java.time classes.

See the OpenJDK issue, [Increase the precision of the implementation of java.time.Clock.systemUTC()](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730). That issue has been successfully implemented.

> `2017-12-23T12:34:56.123456789Z`

On a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with macOS Sierra, I get the current moment in microseconds (up to six digits of decimal fraction).

> `2017-12-23T12:34:56.123456Z`

#### Hardware Clock

Remember that even with a new finer `Clock` implementation, your results may vary by computer. Java depends on the underlying computer hardware’s clock to know the current moment.

- The *resolution* of the hardware clocks vary widely. For example, if a particular computer’s hardware clock supports only [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) granularity, any generated date-time values will have only six digits of fractional second with the last three digits being zeros.
- The *accuracy* of the hardware clocks vary widely. Just because a clock generates a value with several digits of decimal fraction of a second, those digits may be inaccurate, just approximations, adrift from actual time as might be read from an [atomic clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock). In other words, just because you see a bunch of digits to the right of the decimal mark does not mean you can trust the elapsed time between such readings to be true to that minute degree.

Comment: They may resolve to nanoseconds but they are still based on System.currentTimeMillis, so they just add a bunch of 0s on the end. Doesn't help at all if you're trying to get time in micro/nano seconds, the user could just add 0s to the millisecond time manually.

Comment: @annedroiid I covered that in my Answer. In Java 8 you can *store* moments with nanosecond resolution, but *capturing current moment* is only in milliseconds. Remedied in Java 9 with a new implementation of `Clock`. Even so, in Java 8 the java.time classes are helpful for holding values captured by other sources such as microseconds on the Postgres database. But beware of the inaccuracy of values in the microseconds and nanoseconds range; common computer hardware may not carry a hardware clock tracking time that accurately. A value with six or nine digits of fractional second may not be true.

Comment: Isn't it [ChronoUnit.MICROS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MICROS)?

Comment: @Roland Yes, now fixed, thanks. FYI, on Stack Overflow you are invited to directly edit an Answer to fix such a error.

Answer (score 63):

You can use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()):

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// do stuff
long end = System.nanoTime();
long microseconds = (end - start) / 1000;
```

to get time in nanoseconds but it is a strictly relative measure. It has no absolute meaning. It is only useful for comparing to other nano times to measure how long something took to do.

Answer (score 15):

As other posters already indicated; your system clock is probably not synchronized up to microseconds to actual world time. Nonetheless are microsecond precision timestamps useful as a hybrid for both indicating current wall time, and measuring/profiling the duration of things.

I label all events/messages written to a log files using timestamps like "2012-10-21 19:13:45.267128". These convey both *when* it happened ("wall" time), and can also be used to measure the *duration* between this and the next event in the log file (relative difference in microseconds).

To achieve this, you need to link System.currentTimeMillis() with System.nanoTime() and work exclusively with System.nanoTime() from that moment forward. Example code:

```
/**
 * Class to generate timestamps with microsecond precision
 * For example: MicroTimestamp.INSTANCE.get() = "2012-10-21 19:13:45.267128"
 */ 
public enum MicroTimestamp 
{  INSTANCE ;

   private long              startDate ;
   private long              startNanoseconds ;
   private SimpleDateFormat  dateFormat ;

   private MicroTimestamp()
   {  this.startDate = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
      this.startNanoseconds = System.nanoTime() ;
      this.dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") ;
   }

   public String get()
   {  long microSeconds = (System.nanoTime() - this.startNanoseconds) / 1000 ;
      long date = this.startDate + (microSeconds/1000) ;
      return this.dateFormat.format(date) + String.format("%03d", microSeconds % 1000) ;
   }
}
```

Comment: The idea is good, but you must re-synchronize every now and then. The system time (currentTime) and the CPU clock (nanoTime) are NOT in sync, since they are often based on different hardware clocks. Additionally, the time server of your operating system re-synchronizes the system clock with an external time source, if available. Therefore, your seemingly very precise class will produce time stamps that might be way off!

Comment: That code does not appear to be thread safe. Two simultaneous calls to `MicroTimestamp.INSTANCE.get()` could be problematic.

Comment: @Ahmed Why do you think the code is not thread safe? There is nothing in the `get()` method that updates the member variables; it only uses temporary local variables.

Answer (score 9):

You could maybe create a component that determines the offset between System.nanoTime() and System.currentTimeMillis() and effectively get nanoseconds since epoch.

```
public class TimerImpl implements Timer {

    private final long offset;

    private static long calculateOffset() {
        final long nano = System.nanoTime();
        final long nanoFromMilli = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1_000_000;
        return nanoFromMilli - nano;
    }

    public TimerImpl() {
        final int count = 500;
        BigDecimal offsetSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            offsetSum = offsetSum.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(calculateOffset()));
        }
        offset = (offsetSum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(count))).longValue();
    }

    public long nowNano() {
        return offset + System.nanoTime();
    }

    public long nowMicro() {
        return (offset + System.nanoTime()) / 1000;
    }

    public long nowMilli() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Following test produces fairly good results on my machine.

```
    final Timer timer = new TimerImpl();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(timer.nowNano());
        System.out.println(timer.nowMilli());
    }
```

The difference seems to oscillate in range of +-3ms. I guess one could tweak the offset calculation a bit more.

```
1495065607202174413
1495065607203
1495065607202177574
1495065607203
...
1495065607372205730
1495065607370
1495065607372208890
1495065607370
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Instant to compute microseconds since Epoch:

```
val instant = Instant.now();
val currentTimeMicros = instant.getEpochSecond() * 1000_000 + instant.getNano() / 1000;
```

Comment: This works but lacks accuracy, the last 3 digits all get zeroed instead of containing actual microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

a "quick and dirty" solution that I eventually went with:

```
TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(System.nanoTime());
```

UPDATE:

I originally went with System.nanoTime but then I found out it should only be used for elapsed time, I eventually changed my code to work with milliseconds or at some places use:

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMicros(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

but this will just add zeros at the end of the value (micros = millis * 1000)

Left this answer here as a "warning sign" in case someone else thinks of nanoTime :)

Comment: The [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) explicitly says to **not** use `System.nanoTime` for wall-clock time: “This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.”

Comment: @BasilBourque you are correct, after writing this I eventually found out and changed my code but forgot to update here, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3):

Java support microseconds through `TimeUnit` enum.

Here is the java doc:
[Enum TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)

You can get microseconds in java by this way:

```
long microsenconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMicros(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

You also can convert microseconds back to another time units, for example:

```
long seconds = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds(microsenconds);
```

Comment: This is not correct, you will get time in MICRO resolution/length, but time itself will be always only with MILI accuracy (meaning last 3 digits will be always 0).

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in Linux:
If you fish out the source code to "currentTimeMillis()", you'll see that, on Linux, if you call this method, it gets a microsecond time back.   However Java then truncates the microseconds and hands you back milliseconds.  This is partly because Java has to be cross platform so providing methods specifically for Linux was a big no-no back in the day (remember that cruddy soft link support from 1.6 backwards?!).  It's also because, whilst you clock can give you back microseconds in Linux, that doesn't necessarily mean it'll be good for checking the time.  At microsecond levels, you need to know that NTP is not realigning your time and that your clock has not drifted too much during method calls.

This means, in theory, on Linux, you could write a JNI wrapper that is the same as the one in the System package, but not truncate the microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use it for realtime system, perhaps java isnt the best choice to get the timestamp. But  if youre going to use if for unique key, then Jason Smith's answer will do enough. But just in case, to anticipate 2 item end up getting the same timestamp (its possible if those 2 were processed almost simultaneously), you can loop until the last timestamp not equals with the current timestamp.

```
String timestamp = new String();
do {
    timestamp = String.valueOf(MicroTimestamp.INSTANCE.get());
    item.setTimestamp(timestamp);
} while(lasttimestamp.equals(timestamp));
lasttimestamp = item.getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS)
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example of how to create an UnsignedLong current Timestamp:

```
UnsignedLong current = new UnsignedLong(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()).getTime());
```

Comment: Incorrect answer. The java.util.Date class has a resolution of milliseconds, not microseconds specified in the Question. Making a java.sql.Timestamp does not pull additional data out of the air.