# Is System.nanoTime() consistent across threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, timestamp, nanotime

I want to count the time elapsed between two events in nanoseconds. To do that, I can use `System.nanoTime()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java/1712221#1712221). The problem is that the two events are happening in different threads.

---

Since `nanoTime()` doesn't return an absolute timestamp but instead can only be used to calculate time *differences*, I'd like to know if the values I get on the two different threads are consistent with the physical time elapsed between the two events.

Comment: You can can use nanoTime() to calculate the difference from a known time.  This can allow you to get a fairly accurate clock.  I wouldn't suggest using it for times smaller than a micro-second.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's [supposed to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless/4588605#4588605), but due to buggy kernels or hardware, [the answer can be no](http://www.principiaprogramatica.com/?p=16), at least in some environments.

Comment: Also, I once got into trouble when setting `-XX:AggressiveOpts` on Sun JVM lead to unreliable values for System.nanoTime().

Comment: I have no expertise in the matter, but I'll link [this highly upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4588605/1031507) that suggests this linked blog post is incorrect.

Comment: As of OpenJDK 8u192, there are no known unresolved bugs regarding this. The last one appears to be https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184271