# Why is my System.nanoTime() broken?

Tags: java, timestamp, nanotime

Myself and another developer on my time recently moved from a Core 2 Duo machine at work to a new Core 2 Quad 9505; both running Windows XP SP3 32-bit with JDK 1.6.0_18.

Upon doing so, a couple of our automated unit tests for some timing/statistics/metrics aggregation code promptly started failing, due to what appear to be ridiculous values coming back from System.nanoTime().

Test code that shows this behaviour, reliably, on my machine is:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Test;

public class NanoTest {

  @Test
  public void testNanoTime() throws InterruptedException {
    final long sleepMillis = 5000;

    long nanosBefore = System.nanoTime();
    long millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);

    long nanosTaken = System.nanoTime() - nanosBefore;
    long millisTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore;

    System.out.println("nanosTaken="+nanosTaken);
    System.out.println("millisTaken="+millisTaken);

    // Check it slept within 10% of requested time
    assertThat((double)millisTaken, Matchers.closeTo(sleepMillis, sleepMillis * 0.1));
    assertThat((double)nanosTaken, Matchers.closeTo(sleepMillis * 1000000, sleepMillis * 1000000 * 0.1));
  }

}
```

Typical output:

```
millisTaken=5001
nanosTaken=2243785148
```

Running it 100x yields nano results between 33% and 60% of the actual sleep time; usually around 40% though.

I understand the weaknesses in accuracy of timers in Windows, and have read related threads like [Is System.nanoTime() consistent across threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688099/is-system-nanotime-consistent-across-threads), however my understanding is that System.nanoTime() is intended for exactly the purpose we're using it :- measuring elapsed time; more accurately than currentTimeMillis().

Does anyone know why it's returning such crazy results? Is this likely to be a hardware architecture problem (the only major thing that has changed is the CPU/Motherboard on this machine)? A problem with the Windows HAL with my current hardware? A JDK problem? Should I abandon nanoTime()? Should I log a bug somewhere, or any suggestions on how I could investigate further?

**UPDATE 19/07 03:15 UTC**: After trying finnw's test case below I did some more Googling, coming across entries such as [bugid:6440250](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6440250). It also reminded me of some other strange behaviour I noticed late Friday where pings were coming back negative. So I added **/usepmtimer** to my boot.ini and now all the tests behave as expected., and my pings are normal too.

I'm a bit confused about why this was still an issue though; from my reading I thought TSC vs PMT issues were largely resolved in Windows XP SP3. Could it be because my machine was originally SP2, and was patched to SP3 rather than installed originally as SP3? I now also wonder whether I should be installing patches like the one at [MS KB896256](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896256). Maybe I should take this up with the corporate desktop build team?

Comment: Did you get a completely new machine or was your current machine upgraded keeping the old Windows installation?

Comment: Completely new machine; rebuilt on a corporate standard build.

Comment: works fine for me under Windows 7 64 bit latest JDK 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is System.nanoTime() completely useless?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless)

Comment: If somebody comes across this question in 2019 or later: this must not be an issue on any OS since OpenJDK 8u25 or in any versions released later up until February 2019, modulo unknown bugs that might still hide somewhere. See bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8045438

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was resolved (with some open suspicions about the suitability of nanoTime() on multi-core systems!) by adding **/usepmtimer** to the end of my **C:\boot.ini** string; forcing Windows to use the Power Management timer rather than the TSC. It's an open question as to why I needed to do this given I'm on XP SP3, as I understood that this was the default, however perhaps it was due to the manner in which my machine was patched to SP3.

Comment: Wow - am I glad I found this post - had one customer site where ScheduledExecutorService was going completely off the rails (time remaining until next scheduled task would randomly go in the wrong direction).

Comment: Glad it helped someone! I lost a lot of time to this :) I also imagine as XP becomes less and less used now that it's properly EOLed (especially by developers themselves) the ability to quickly diagnose such obscure problems on old customer kit will gradually reduce....

Answer (score 2):

On my system (Windows 7 64-Bit, Core i7 980X):

```
nanosTaken=4999902563
millisTaken=5001
```

System.nanoTime() uses OS-specific calls, so I expect that you are seeing a bug in your Windows/processor combination.

Comment: Thanks mikera, it looks like Windows was using a timer style that does not behave correctly on my Core 2 Quad. Forcing it to use the Power Management Timer has made it behave normally again; but I don't quite understand why I had to do this!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to read the answers to this other stack overflow question: [Is System.nanoTime() completely useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless).

In summary, it would appear that nanoTime relies on operating system timers that may be affected by the presence of multiple core CPUs. As such, nanoTime may not be that useful on certain combinations of OS and CPU, and care should be taken when using it in portable Java code that you intend to run on multiple target platforms. There seems to be a lot of complaining on the web on this subject, but not much consensus on a meaningful alternative.

Comment: This is not a completetly accurate summary. System.nanoTime depends on OS-specific timers. There have been one or two bugs in the past, e.g. on the Athlon 64 chips in Windows, however on most systems you can rely on nanoTime to work pretty well. I use it for animation and timing in multi-core games, and have never had any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification mikera. I've updated my answer to (hopefully) improve the accuracy.

Comment: Thanks Tom. As I've mentioned in the updated question above, I managed to return to "normal" behaviour by forcing use of the PMT. I guess I still have niggling concerns about whether this will behave the way we expect across multiple cores though. And yes, without a meaningful alternative (short of "go back to currentTimeMillis") it's difficult to know how best to proceed!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell whether this is a bug or just normal timer variation between cores.

An experiment you could try is to use native calls to force the thread to run on a specific core.

Also, to rule out power management effects, try spinning in a loop as an alternative to `sleep()`:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32API;

public class AffinityTest {

    private static void testNanoTime(boolean sameCore, boolean spin)
    throws InterruptedException {
        W32API.HANDLE hThread = kernel.GetCurrentThread();
        final long sleepMillis = 5000;

        kernel.SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, new NativeLong(1L));
        Thread.yield();
        long nanosBefore = System.nanoTime();
        long millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();

        kernel.SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, new NativeLong(sameCore? 1L: 2L));
        if (spin) {
            Thread.yield();
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore < sleepMillis)
                ;
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
        }

        long nanosTaken = System.nanoTime() - nanosBefore;
        long millisTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore;

        System.out.println("nanosTaken="+nanosTaken);
        System.out.println("millisTaken="+millisTaken);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Sleeping, different cores");
        testNanoTime(false, false);
        System.out.println("\nSleeping, same core");
        testNanoTime(true, false);
        System.out.println("\nSpinning, different cores");
        testNanoTime(false, true);
        System.out.println("\nSpinning, same core");
        testNanoTime(true, true);
    }

    private static final Kernel32Ex kernel =
        (Kernel32Ex) Native.loadLibrary(Kernel32Ex.class);

}

interface Kernel32Ex extends Kernel32 {
    NativeLong SetThreadAffinityMask(HANDLE hThread, NativeLong dwAffinityMask);
}
```

If you get very different results depending on core selection (e.g. 5000ms on the same core but 2200ms on different cores) that would suggest that the problem is just natural timer variation between cores.

If you get very different results from sleeping vs. spinning, it is more likely due to power management slowing down the clocks.

If *none* of the four results are close to 5000ms, then it might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks finnw, this is interesting. My results are:

    Sleeping, different cores
    nanosTaken=2049217124
    millisTaken=4985

    Sleeping, same core
    nanosTaken=1808868148
    millisTaken=4985

    Spinning, different cores
    nanosTaken=5015172794
    millisTaken=5000

    Spinning, same core
    nanosTaken=5015295288
    millisTaken=5000

Do you think this implies something broken with power management on my machine?

Comment: After doing some more reading, triggered by your test I tried rebooting my machine with /usepmtimer in boot.ini. Now your test, (and my original tests) behave normally.

I've edited my question accordingly. Should I have to do this?

Comment: It is not necessarily "broken" but it is clear that the TSC is not suitable for high-precision timing on your machine and using the PM timer gives better results.  I thought /usepmtimer was the default on XP SP3 but your results suggest otherwise.

Comment: Yes, well my machine was actually an SP2 machine recently patched to SP3 via some kind of corporate patching process, which may or may not have adulterated the standard MS SP3 distribution; or perhaps when SP3 is applied as a patch the boot.ini is not changed. Not sure.