# scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate() strange behaviour

Tags: java

I have this simple test:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ScheduleTest {

  private static long last;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    last = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        Long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(current - last);
        last = current;

      }
    }, 0, 1000);
  }
}
```

which give me expected result:

> 0
>   1000
>   1000
>   1000

If I replace Timer by a ScheduleThreadPoool, it gives me weird result:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduleTest {

  private static long last;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    last = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    last = System.currentTimeMillis();
    scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {

        Long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(current - last);
        last = current;

      }
    }, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }
}
```

Result:

> ```
> 0
> 2359
> 2079
> 2312
> 1844
> 2266
> ```

Any expectation?

Comment: I didn't get the same result as you, I got `2, 1000, 999, 1000, ...`.  This was using jdk1.6.0_25.

Comment: I have noticed I have the same issue for a Swing animation. However, Timer is as erratic as ScheduledThreadPools and my results are even worse than yours, with many dt = 0.  My guess is that it has to do with the processor. I have a 5 year old Core Duo 2 and Java 7.

Comment: I'm on XP 64 bits and tested with jdk1.6.0_16 (64 and 32 bits) and jdk1.6.0_27 with same erratic results. My CPU is an intel core duo E8500 à 3.16GHz.

Comment: I also tested this on a linux, with expected results (better precision with ScheduledThreadPool than timer). I don't know if it's a OS or CPU problem.

Comment: True... the OS might play a role too.

Comment: By the way: As `last` is accessed from different threads (the main thread and the scheduled thread), you should declare it volatile. Otherwise, Java does not guarantee that one thread sees the value written by another.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a clue.

ScheduledThreadPool use a DelayQueue to store next tasks to launch. DelayQueue use System.nanoTime() to compute remaining time before task can be run.

But System.nanoTime() seems buggy on my PC (XP 64 SP2):

```
    while (true) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
        LockSupport.parkNanos(Thread.currentThread(), 1000000000);
        System.out.println("after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " - nanos: "
                + (System.nanoTime() - startNanos) + " - nanos converted: "
                + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - startNanos));
    }
```

Results:

```
after: 1000 - nanos: 499769959 - nanos converted: 500
after: 1000 - nanos: 415454114 - nanos converted: 415
after: 1000 - nanos: 416274224 - nanos converted: 416
after: 1000 - nanos: 416141257 - nanos converted: 416
after: 1000 - nanos: 418547153 - nanos converted: 418
```

So replanification of task is not correct based on biaised nanos. Timer uses System.currentTimeMillis() that works well.

There are lots of discussions about System.nanoTimes():

[Is System.nanoTime() completely useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless)

[Why is my System.nanoTime() broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274892/why-is-my-system-nanotime-broken)

Comment: As I mentioned above in the comments, currentTimeMillis is as bad on my system.  I looked at the api  of both functions and they warn about  having no guarantee of accuracy.