# System.nanoTime() turns negative

Tags: java

When attempting to investigate the runtime of various tasks using `System.nanoTime()`, the value, when the input data-set is large enough, turns negative.

The example code used:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
run();
long stop = System.nanoTime();

int diff = (int) (stop-start);
System.out.println(data_size+", "+diff);
```

The output, when invoking `run()` on an increasingly big data-set, looks like this:

```
1, 80000
10, 4310000
50, 48077000
100, 171363000
250, 1061924000
500, 14018704
750, 998074408
1000, -41025184
1500, -81710664
2000, -273795736
2500, 768997600
3000, -39161248
```

Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I get a negative elapsed time using System.nanoTime()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866206/why-i-get-a-negative-elapsed-time-using-system-nanotime)

Comment: @turbo This is not a duplicate of that question; this is caused by casting to the difference to `int`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You casting the difference between two `long` to an `int`.  Likely, your `long` difference is longer than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (about 2 billion) and the cast to `int` takes the last 32 bits, yielding a negative number.  Besides, 2 billion nanoseconds is only 2 seconds, so any time longer that will overflow an `int`.

Keep the difference as a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is an *integer overflow* issue. `int` range is in:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648
```

Try using `long` to store `diff` value instead:

```
long diff = stop - start;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, an the maximum number for an int (represented by 32 bits) is 2^31 or 2,147,483,647.
What is happening is that when the difference is greater than this number, it can't be represented by an int and overflows (ran out of bits)