# Java library for dealing with win32 FILETIME?

Tags: java

Are there any Java libraries around for dealing with the win32 [FILETIME/](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) time intervals ?
It's basically a 64 bit timestamp in 100ns intervals since January 1, 1601.

(For my particular needs, converting to/from java.util.Date or an appropriate joda time equivalent would do, although I'll need access to at least microsecond resolution - which neither seems to provide.)

Comment: Why exactly do you need that high resolution?

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java ?

Comment: Standard computer clocks can't even manage millisecond accuracy, never mind microsecond. Sounds like a classic case of precision over accuracy.

Comment: @Thomas The timestamps are done in hardware, on E1/T1 cards whose clocks are locked to a reference signal which according to ITU G.811 needs an accuracy of 1x10 E-11 sec. (i.e. we don't get these timestamps from an unpredicatble OS call)

Answer (score 8):

If you are fine with millisecond resolution, this would work:

```
/** Difference between Filetime epoch and Unix epoch (in ms). */
private static final long FILETIME_EPOCH_DIFF = 11644473600000L;

/** One millisecond expressed in units of 100s of nanoseconds. */
private static final long FILETIME_ONE_MILLISECOND = 10 * 1000;

public static long filetimeToMillis(final long filetime) {
    return (filetime / FILETIME_ONE_MILLISECOND) - FILETIME_EPOCH_DIFF;
}

public static long millisToFiletime(final long millis) {
    return (millis + FILETIME_EPOCH_DIFF) * FILETIME_ONE_MILLISECOND;
}
```

At this point, converting from ms to a Date object is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Java 8+ `java.time` based solution that keeps 100-nanosecond precision:

```
public static final Instant ZERO = Instant.parse("1601-01-01T00:00:00Z");

public static long fromInstant(Instant instant) {
    Duration duration = Duration.between(ZERO, instant);
    return duration.getSeconds() * 10_000_000 + duration.getNano() / 100;
}

public static Instant toInstant(long fileTime) {
    Duration duration = Duration.of(fileTime / 10, ChronoUnit.MICROS).plus(fileTime % 10 * 100, ChronoUnit.NANOS);
    return ZERO.plus(duration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I solved this using JNI... (Although not on Windows, this was unix)

That is, a piece of C++ code that called the native OS functions, and then called that code using Java Native Interface.

A bit clunky, but it was the only way I could find (Also needed the i-node).

EDIT: Assuming the values are already obtained from some other source, Date4J can handle seconds with 9 decimals, but it is not as feature rich as Joda.

Comment: Looks like the OP doesn't need to fetch a native windows timestamp, but rather just deal with values representing a win32 timestamp

Comment: But assuming he has one and just want to manipulate it, Joda does not have microsecond resolution. Date4J has up to 9 decimal places resolution though (on seconds). But its not as feature rich as Joda.

Comment: Well, I parse the timestamp from (ASN.1/DER encoded) files simply. They're just a 64 bit number. I'll take a look at Date4j.