# Retrieve current date and time from "lockouttime" attribute

Tags: java, active-directory

In Active Directory, "lockOutTime" attribute has a long value. How do I calculate the date and time from that value (in order to find at what time the user is locked)?

Comment: Waht about `new Date(<long value>)`?

Comment: @Uwe Allner that does not produce exact value

Comment: It's a FILETIME - perhaps something like this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398557/java-library-for-dealing-with-win32-filetime

Answer (score 1):

I work with this method..

```
private final static long DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATES = 11644473600000L + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

Date getDateFromAD(long adLongValue)
{
    long milliseconds = (adLongValue / 10000) - DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATES;
    Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need to add 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 to DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATES, which means the following is enough,

```
private final static long DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATES = 11644473600000L;
```

You can double check the result with https://www.epochconverter.com/ldap.