# How to get the microseconds from a Date?

Tags: java, datetime, date

I am trying to get microseconds from a `Date`, but I can't.

```
Date date = new Date()
```

Comment: can you please explain a little more

Comment: possible duplicate of [Current time in microseconds in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java)

Comment: Adding a "shouting" edit doesn't really help your question at all...

Answer (score 16):

No, `Date` only stores values to millisecond accuracy. If you want microsecond accuracy, you might want to look at [JSR-310](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen), or [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) as a bit of a hack - but don't expect any of the built-in classes such as `Calendar` and `DateFormat` to handle anything beyond milliseconds.

If you're trying to perform *timing* (e.g. for benchmarking) you should use [`System.nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29), but that should *only* be used for stopwatch-like use cases - it *doesn't* give you the "current wallclock time" in a meaningful way.

Comment: You can see example following the link to API.

Comment: @SalmanRaza: It's hard to give an example when we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i am trying to achive just the microsecond portion of this time "2012-01-03 12:50:49" in a seprate variable!

Comment: @SalmanRaza: Well the microsecond portion of *that* time is just 0. It's still unclear what you're really trying to do - find the *current* time to microsecond accuracy, or read some *other* date/time to microsecond accuracy. If it's the latter, where is that time stored, and how?

Comment: @jon ok then how would i get the microsecond portion of the current time ?

Comment: @SalmanRaza: You can't, generally - the system clock used in Java only reports time to the millisecond, which is generally more precise than the *real* accuracy anyway. You could investigate whether there's an NTP implementation somewhere and try to use that, I suppose. You really need to differentiate between whether your question is primarily about *representation* or *obtaining* data though - they're really different questions.

Comment: @Jon i dont know why are you not getting me .. . its simple that i want get current date time either by "Datetime" or "Calender" by any mean it possible but for that current time i want to get its microsecond at any cost how would i implement it in JAVA ??

Comment: @SalmanRaza: Neither `Date` nor `Calendar` provides that degree of precision, and nothing within Java will give you the current date/time to that degree of accuracy. `Timestamp` can *represent* a value down to nanoseconds, but normally that value is provided by a database.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is find the difference between the currentTimeMillis and the nanoTime() at regular intervals (as this drifts quite a bit) and use nanoTime() + OFFSET for a currentTimeNS.  (More specificity I use the RDTSC machine code instruction, which comes with even more quibbles ;)

However, its is less accurate than currenTimeMillis() over time which itself can drifts by many milli-seconds in an hour.

It only really useful if you understand its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

To measure time in microseconds you need to use the System.nanoTime() function which will return a time in microseconds based on the most accurate clock available to your system.

To the user this acts in pretty much the same way as System.currentTimeMilis() does for milliseconds, you simply define your start and end times and then negate the difference to find out how long an action took. For example:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//Do some kind of processing; 
//loop, IO, whatever you want to measure
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
```

The last bit can be shorted, I've left it verbose for simplicity:

```
long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

This should not be used to measure real time as it has very little meaning or guarantee that it is even comparable to it. All of the above information is available from the Java API documentation for [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29).