# Using validation in Spring to restrict ZonedDateTime field to 3 digits at millisecond time

Tags: java, spring, validation, hibernate-validator

I have an input DTO in a Spring MVC request that I want to validate, specifically the ZonedDateTime field should at most contain 3 digits at millisecond level, i.e. it cannot be the full nanoseconds precision. Other than that the input request should follow the ISO datetime format. I could make the field a String and then just restrict it with a regex but I prefer to keep it as an ZonedDateTime so I don't need to parse it again.

The object looks like this:

```
@Data
public class MeasurementDTO {

    private ZonedDateTime date;
    @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 8) private BigDecimal value;

}
```

And this is a nested DTO where the parent object comes in as a `@RequestBody` with the `@Valid` annotation.

I've tried @JsonFormat but I can't seem to restrict the millisecond part.
Is there any way to do this or should I just parse it myself as a String and then deal with it? Or even just leave it at ZonedDateTime and then check the nanosecond component to see if it's there in a custom validator?

Thanks to Tim's answer I remembered Java `Date`s don't have more precision than millis anyway, so I updated the question to use `ZonedDateTime`s which do have up to nanosecond precision. I do want to be able to give the user a warning if they do attempt to pass more precision, if using Date this information would just get swallowed.

Comment: If you want greater than millisecond resolution, use `java.time.Instant` with much finer resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Best to always avoid `java.util.Date` entirely as it is crippled by bad design choices. To lop off any microseconds or nanos in an `Instant`, call the [`truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) method. Pass [`ChronoUnit.MILLIS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MILLIS).

Comment: @BasilBourque I already edited Instant into my answer. I actually do not want greater than millisecond resolution for this case, but I would like to be able to detect it if users try to pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this the hard way with a custom validator. I am still welcoming answers that do this in a more concise way though.

Here's my solution:

I added an annotation @ValidMeasurementInput

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MeasurementValidator.class)
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidMeasurementInput {

    String message() default "Invalid measurement input";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And implemented a custom validator

```
public class MeasurementValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidMeasurementInput, MetricsDTO> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MetricsDTO metricsDTO, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Somewhere in this class among some other validations is this code:

```
   int nano = measurementDTO.getDate().getNano();
   int remainderAfterMillis = nano % 1000000;
   if (remainderAfterMillis != 0)
       valid = false;
```

And of course I added the `@ValidMeasurementInput` to my DTO.

Answer (score 1):

You may not consider this to be a complete answer, but `java.util.Date` only stores precision up to milliseconds, and not beyond that.  See Jon Skeet's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756982/how-to-get-the-microseconds-from-a-date), or read the [source code for CalendarDate](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/util/calendar/CalendarDate.java), which reveals that it has nothing beyond millisecond storage.

So, there is no sense in restricting a `Date` to millisecond precision with Hibernate validation, because the type itself already carries this restriction.

Comment: That is actually a very good point! I was porting this code from a python function where I was using a monstrous regex, but it's not even needed here. Leaving the question open for a while to see if there are any answers that do allow validating part of the time though, even for example restricting on seconds.

Comment: I decided to use ZonedDateTime in my DTO anyway because I don't want to silently swallow the extra precision.