# How to print time up to 6 digits of precision for seconds value

Tags: java, date, timestamp, design-patterns

I have a value in column which is of type timestamp. Lets say I have a value **2007-05-04 08:48:40.969774**

Now, when trying to fetch the value from the database and return this timestamp value to a function, what SimpleDateFormatter pattern should I use so that the fraction part beside the seconds also gets returned.

I have used **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss**, but that only returns till the seconds and ignores the fraction present beside the seconds(.969774). I need help in returning this fraction part also, with a 6-digits precision.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.  There's a list of format specifiers there.

Comment: whoever downvoted care to explain why? There is nothing wrong with the question. Is it possible to get millionth second precision in java.

Comment: +1 I think its a reasonable question.  I imagine the downvoter didn't realise that dealing with micro-seconds a) is not trivial or b) quite possible.

Comment: I think Timestamp can deal with nanoseconds from a database, take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Answer (score 8):

The default ways of formatting a `java.util.Date` (or `java.sql.Timestamp`) has only millisecond precision. You can use `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS` to get that millisecond precision.

A `java.sql.Timestamp` actually does have (up to) nanosecond precision (assuming the database server and the driver actually support it). The easiest way to format it in Java 8 is to convert the timestamp to a `java.time.LocalDateTime` (using `Timestamp.toLocalDateTime()`) and use the `java.time` formatting options in `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` which support up to nanoseconds.

If you use Java 7 or earlier it will take some extra effort, as the normal date formatters don't support it. For example you could use a dateformatter with pattern `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` (to only format up to seconds) and append the sub-second nano seconds (with appropriate zero-padding) of `Timestamp.getNanos()` yourself.

Comment: Great answer. In the Java7 case you can save the zero-padding code by calling the `toString()` method of `java.sql.Timestamp` and take the already zero-padded nanos with `substring` as they always start at the same position. Or you can just use `toString()` if the format is okay for you. :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to have a way of obtaining a micro-second timestamp. I use System.currentTimeMillis() with System.nanoTime() in combination.  Then you need a way to display it. You can divide it by 1000 and display milliseconds as normal, then display the last 3 digits of the time. i.e. Have a time which is like

```
long timeUS = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000 + micros;
```

here is a more detailed example

[HiresTimer.java](http://code.google.com/p/core-java-performance-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/code/java/core/time/HiresTimer.java) and [HiresTimerTest.java](http://code.google.com/p/core-java-performance-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/com/google/code/java/core/time/HiresTimerTest.java)

The test prints

```
2012/04/09T14:22:13.656008
2012/04/09T14:22:13.656840
2012/04/09T14:22:13.656958
2012/04/09T14:22:13.657066
 ....
2012/04/09T14:22:13.665249
2012/04/09T14:22:13.665392
2012/04/09T14:22:13.665473
2012/04/09T14:22:13.665581
```

---

EDIT: The relevant code is

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
private static final DecimalFormat DF = new DecimalFormat("000");

public static String toString(long timeUS) {
    return SDF.format(timeUS / 1000) + DF.format(timeUS % 1000);
}
```

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` does not return a value that has any correlation to an absolute time. It is only useful for measuring elapsed time between two invocations of `System.nanoTime()`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1712205/260633

Comment: And it can measure the elapse time from currentTimeMillis which means you can have a fair idea what the micro-seconds are.

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` cannot measure anything except elapsed time since the last call to `System.nanoTime()`. The epoch is undefined. So it is only useful in comparison to itself.

Comment: And so you can determine for example, how many micro-second it has been since you last called currentTimeMillis. Once you determine when the currentTimeMillis last changed, you have a known point in time from which to count micro-seconds, or even nano-seconds.

Comment: I am guessing the downvoter didn't read the code, and hasn't tried to use currentTimeMillis() and nanoTime() together.

Comment: @Dev How does what you have said make any sense given the output of the test quoted?

Comment: For the record, it wasn't my downvote. That being said the question was asking about text formatting, not how to obtain a microsecond timestamp.

Comment: @Dev, I suspected you weren't the downvoter.  You are right to point out the question is about formatting.  This partially depends on what data type you are trying to format. I have included my example so you don't have to click on a link.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with micro- or nano-seconds in Java is not always straightforward.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date d = new Date(time);
    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(time);
    /* micro-seconds as OP requested */
    {
      t.setNanos(123456000);
      System.out.println(d);
      System.out.println(t);
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.'");
      NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("000000");
      System.out.println(df.format(t.getTime()) + nf.format(t.getNanos() / 1000));
      /* using Java Time API (available since JDK 1.8) */
      DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
      LocalDateTime ldt = t.toLocalDateTime();
      System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));
    }
    /* nanoseconds just for the sake of completness */
    {
      t.setNanos(123456789);
      System.out.println(t);
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.'");
      NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("000000000");
      System.out.println(df.format(t.getTime()) + nf.format(t.getNanos()));
      /* using Java Time API (available since JDK 1.8) */
      DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn");
      LocalDateTime ldt = t.toLocalDateTime();
      System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));
    }
  }
}
```

The output produced is (in my country, my locale):

```
Tue Aug 31 13:26:08 CEST 2021
2021-08-31 13:26:08.123456
2021-08-31 13:26:08.123456
2021-08-31 13:26:08.123456
2021-08-31 13:26:08.123456789
2021-08-31 13:26:08.123456789
2021-08-31 13:26:08.123456789
```

Comment: The problem is that the micro/nano-seconds are always zero.

Comment: I presume they can be set by the database subsystem (according to the question). I edited the code to demonstrate that...

Comment: Actually, the Question was regarding microseconds not nanoseconds.

Comment: I edited the code to reflect microseconds as requested by the OP. Also added Java Time API version used to format the Timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 and later, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package has support for parsing and manipulating date/times to nanosecond precision. That means up to 9 digits in the fraction of a second.

Comment: Could you provide and example?