# how to get full time-stamp value from oracle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c

I have a column in oracle in time stamp format, it has a value like this **05-MAY-17 11.01.17.939951000 AM**. when my java code picks that roe and when I do a ResultSet.getString("coulmn name"), I am getting value like this
 **2017-05-05 11:01:17.939**. is there a way I can get full value for that field.

Comment: Why are you using getString to get a timestamp?

Comment: I did ResultSet.getTimestamp() as well. got the same result @AlexPoole

Comment: Your talking about getting 100th of microseconds? Perhaps the JDBC driver conversion of date has lost precision. Have you tried reading using timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

[How to print time up to 6 digits of precision for seconds value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073813/how-to-print-time-up-to-6-digits-of-precision-for-seconds-value)

The last answer on the page shows a solution that goes up to 9 values for the seconds.  This might help you.