# Timed movement java game

Tags: java

```
    Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    boolean checkTime = true;





        if (checkTime == true)
            before=date1.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        checkTime=false;

        after=date2.get(Calendar.SECOND);   

        difference= after-before;
```

I have it so that the before variable will become a static second, and it will keep recalculating the after time, and get the difference between the two. However it seems to only update the 'after' variable once, resulting in a difference of 0.

Ps. this is for a game that I'm playing with and I'm trying to make the movement relative to time.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Seems like parts of your code are missing...?

Comment: There is no difference, processor speed can calculate in milli seconds thatz better. Only a fraction of difference will be there.

Comment: Seems to me it would be better to use a timer for this

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
```

gets a Calendar that is initailized with the current date and time.  After that it does not change, so `after` will always be the same value.   If you are wanting new current time each iteration you will need to create a new instance (or use `System.currentTimeMillis()`) each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cases you will get 0 because your lines of code are executed in less than a millisecond. There is also the runtime optimization and GC playing their roles.

All in all, you cannot be sure of the result being non-zero.

You could try something like this,

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
try{
Thread.sleep(1000);
}catch(Exception e){}
Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Got difference as 1.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java) too.