# Java Date and Timestamp

Tags: java, date, timestamp

Consider this code:-

```
        String t = "2013-10-05 09:10:37.029074";
        Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(t);

        Date d = new Date(ts.getTime());
        Timestamp ts2 = new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime());
        System.out.println("ts -->"+ts);
        System.out.println("ts2-->"+ts2);
```

When I run this, I get the result as.

```
ts -->2013-10-05 09:10:37.029074           ts2-->2013-10-05 09:10:37.029
```

I do NOT want to ignore milisecods (Please see the diff between 029074 and 029). It seems to be rounding.

I want to preserve even the fraction.

Comment: If you **must** maintain microsecond precision, is there a specific reason you **must** use `Date`s?

Comment: look there - i hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java

Comment: What you don't want to ignore(`074`) is actually the microseconds part of time. `029` is the milliseconds part.

Answer (score 6):

`Timestamp` has [nanosecond](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) precision. Both [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) and [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) have only millisecond precision. Once you bring either `Date` into the game, you will lose precision.

So just keep the `Timestamp` around and grab its milliseconds with `getTime` to do whatever you need to do but make sure you hold onto it.

Answer (score 5):

The `Date` class only has millisecond precision.  It cannot store higher precision.

[Javadocs for `Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Both of the troublesome `Date` & `Timestamp` classes are now replaced by `java.time.Instant`.

```
Instant.now() 
       .toString()
```

> 2018-04-04T21:33:37.889228Z

## java.time

The [Answer by Vidya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578144/642706) and [by rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19577993/642706) are both correct, you have run into the limits designed in those classes.

Also, those classes are troublesome, confusing, and flawed. They have been supplanted by the *java.time* classes. No need to ever use `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` again.

The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with resolution of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). That class is now replaced by [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), also a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), but with a finer resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

In Java 8 specifically, *capturing* the current moment is limited to milliseconds despite the `Instant` class being capable of *holding* nanoseconds. In Java 9 and later, a fresh implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) allows for capturing the current moment in finer resolution, though limited by the capability of your host OS & hardware. In Oracle JDK 9.0.4 on macOS Sierra, I am seeing microseconds

> Instant.now().toString(): 2018-04-04T21:33:37.889228Z

The `java.sql.Timestamp` class is also replaced by `Instant` as of JDBC 4.2 and later. You can now directly exchange *java.time* classes, and forget about the java.sql types.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).