# Any new method to get current time with accuracy in microseconds in Java now?

Tags: java, time, java-7

I checked the below page that there is no method to get current time with accuracy in microsecond in Java in 2009.
[Current time in microseconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java)

The best one is System.currentTimeMillis() which gives current time with accuracy in millisecond, while System.nanoTime() gives the current timestamp with accuracy in nanoseconds, but this timestamp could not be used to convert to current time with high accuracy.

May I know if there is any new update in this for Java after 6 years? Thanks.

Edit 1. System.nanoTime() is useful for estimating duration, but not giving current time.

Edit 2. It is good to have solutions in Java 8. Is there any other way to do it in Java 7? Thanks!

Comment: Nanoseconds are more precise than microseconds. Also a solution was provided in your [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33129599/4105457)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.currentTimeMillis vs System.nanoTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime)

Comment: Of course the precision of the timing logic is fully operating system and hardware dependent, it is not actually Java producing the numbers.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks, I have deleted my comment. I wrote that comment long back without fully understand that the OP is looking for accuracy.

Answer (score 15):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
```

> 2018-03-09T21:03:33.831515Z

Using [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later, you can likely capture the current moment with [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) resolution.

Example seen above is Oracle Java 9.0.4 for [macOS Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra). Note the 6 digits of fractional second, meaning microseconds.

---

## java.time

The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later has classes to represent date-time values with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), 9 digits of a decimal fraction of a second.

### Java 9

The [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) implementation of Java 9 has a [fresh implementation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730) of `Clock` with up to nanosecond resolution. Actual values depend on the limits of the underlying hardware clock of any particular computer.

For more info see the Question, [Why does the new Java 8 Date Time API not have nanosecond precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33477695/642706).

Avoid the older date-time classes. The classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar bundled with early versions of Java have only millisecond resolution. Same for [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Both are supplanted by the java.time classes.

### Java 8

Java 8 implements the [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) interface with only [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution (3 digits of a fractional second). So while the java.time classes are capable of *carrying* nanoseconds, it is not able to *capture* the current time with nanoseconds.

## Native code

Perhaps you could write or find an implementation of [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) that makes a call to a native library in the host OS to get a more accurate time.

## Database

If you happen to be using a database already, you could ask it for the time. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

```
Instant instant = myPreparedStatement.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Prior to JDBC 4.2, you could go through the troublesome legacy `java.sql.Timestamp` that carries nanosecond resolution. For example, [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) provides [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) resolution (assuming the host computer clock supports that), 6 digits of a fractional second. You can convert from a `java.sql.Timestamp` to an `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` using new methods added to the old classes.

[image]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

The Java 8 [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package has what you need.

Try:

```
LocalDateTime.now(); // The current timestamp accurate to nanoseconds
LocalDateTime.now().getLong(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND); // the microseconds part
LocalDateTime.now().getLong(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND); // even finer
LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth(); // main parts of the date have their own methods
LocalDateTime.now().getMonth(); // etc
```

To just get nanos as a String, use `nnnnnnnnn` in the format:

```
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn"));
```

Comment: Parse it to a Date object and further if you need more formatting use `SimpleDateFormatter`

Comment: @JudeNiroshan FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get current time from the new Java 8 java.time is the [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class

```
Clock.systemUTC().millis()
```

gives current time in millis (long value millis since epoch) or

```
Clock.systemUTC().instant()
```

returns an instance of [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class "which represents the start of a nanosecond on the timeline" according to [the official Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/instant.html).  The tutorial shows how to work with the new class, convert to local or UTC or zoned date time, etc

Comment: Which of these gives you the time in microseconds?