# LocalDateTime.now() has different levels of precision on Windows and Mac machine

Tags: java, precision, java-time, platform

When creating a new `LocalDateTime` using `LocalDateTime.now()` on my Mac and Windows machine i get a nano **precision of 6** on my Mac and a nano **precision of 3** on my Windows machine. Both are running `jdk-1.8.0-172`.

- Is it possible to limit or increase the precision on one of the
  machines?
- And why is the precision actually different?

Comment: [`LocalDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now()) uses the [system `Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#systemDefaultZone()) which means whatever precision the system clock has that's how much precision `LocalDateTime.now()` will have.

Comment: "milliseconds precision of 6" is that the same as microsecond precision? (Perhaps better phrased as "subsecond precision").

Comment: Sorry! It´s actually called "nano".

Comment: @Slaw Running `System.currentTimeMillis()` provides the same level of precision on both machines.

Comment: @TobiasMarschall because that's the time with *milli*second precision.

Comment: The system `Clock` may use `System.currentTimeMillis()` _or a higher resolution clock if available_. It looks like your Mac has a clock with microsecond precision.

Comment: Is there some kind of "default clock" that can provide the same level of presicion on both machines?

Comment: By the way, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class when your intention is to track moments. Use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` instead. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, the `LocalDateTime` *cannot* track moments.

Comment: Whose implementation of Java 8 are you using on macOS? I do not know of any that can capture current moment in microseconds. See OpenJDK issue ticket `JDK-8068730`, [*Increase the precision of the implementation of java.time.Clock.systemUTC()*](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)  Discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33477695/642706).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The precision is different because [`LocalDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now()) uses a system default [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html).

> Obtains the current date-time from the system clock in the default time-zone.
>
> This will query the [system clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#systemDefaultZone()) in the default time-zone to obtain the current date-time.
>
> ...

The link in this Javadoc takes you to `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` which states (**emphasis** mine):

> Obtains a clock that returns the current instant using the best available system clock, converting to date and time using the default time-zone.
>
> This clock is based on the best available system clock. **This may use [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), or a higher resolution clock if one is available.**
>
> ...

Which clock Java uses can depend on a lot of things and it looks like your Mac computer has a clock with *micro*second precision whereas your Windows computer has a clock with *milli*second precision. I'm not aware of any way to *increase* the precision of a clock but you can definitely *decrease* the precision so that it matches across platforms.

One option is to use [`LocalDateTime.truncatedTo(TemporalUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)):

```java
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant original = Instant.now();
    System.out.printf("Original instant  : %s%n", original);

    Instant truncated = original.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    System.out.printf("Truncated instant : %s%n", truncated);
  }
}
```

<sup>*-[Also see answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52030034/6395627)*</sup>

Another option is to plug in your own `Clock` and use [`LocalDateTime.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now(java.time.Clock)). If possible, I would use [`Clock.tickMillis(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#tickMillis(java.time.ZoneId)) since this method returns a `Clock` that truncates to milliseconds.

> Obtains a clock that returns the current instant ticking in whole milliseconds using the best available system clock.
>
> This clock will always have the nano-of-second field truncated to milliseconds. This ensures that the visible time ticks in whole milliseconds. The underlying clock is the best available system clock, equivalent to using system(ZoneId).
>
> ...
>
> **Since:**
> 9

For example:

```java
import java.time.Clock;
// import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Java 8
    // Clock clock = Clock.tick(Clock.systemDefaultZone(), Duration.ofMillis(1));

    // Java 9+
    Clock clock = Clock.tickMillis(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    Instant instant = Instant.now(clock);
    System.out.printf("Instant : %s%n", instant);
  }
}
```

Comment: In other words, resolution of current moment is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 12):

I don’t think you can get any better precision than the one you are already getting. If you want to reduce the precision to match that of the other system, it’s straightforward (when you know how):

```
LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
```

The precision you get depends on the hardware, the settings, the OS and the integration of the JVM with all of those. It’s well known that Mac generally offers better precision than Windows (though I was under the impression that this was only the case from Java 9, per OpenJDK issue # [JDK‑8068730](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)).

Comment: is ZoneID needed? maybe a bit confusing, at least it is kind of hiding the important part (laptop)

Comment: A good habit if you want to control what you get, @CarlosHeuberger. If you want the JVM’s default time zone in that moment, I still prefer `ZoneId.systemDefault()` over leaving it out. It reads the intention more clearly, though the result is the same. You are correct that this discussion is not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: sure, there are a lot of 'good habits'... like having a constant for such? like avoiding too long lines?

Answer (score 10):

If anyone had the same issue with `Instant` precision on `mac` or `ubuntu` on Java 15 that I want to show the difference:

mac Instant precision: `2021-03-10T12:28:19.228816Z`

ubuntu Instant precision: `2021-03-10T12:28:19.228816800Z`

Solution: please add `.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)` to `Instant` variable if You want to have the same precision on this OS

Answer (score 0):

You can set the precision using a formatter, without resorting to `truncatedTo` or `Clock.tickMillis`:

```
jshell> OffsetDateTime.now().format(ISO_DATE_TIME)
$5 ==> "2020-10-21T10:13:48.57776451+02:00"

jshell> OffsetDateTime.now().format(ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ"))
$8 ==> "2020-10-21T10:15:31.27+0200"
```

I realized this after discovering that [JDK 15 has different precision on macOS and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444357/why-does-jdk-15s-time-api-have-increased-precision-on-linux-but-not-on-macos?noredirect=1&lq=1).