# Why does JDK 15's time API have increased precision on Linux, but not on macOS?

Tags: java, java-time, java-14, java-15

`java.time.OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)` on OpenJDK 15 (build 36) on Linux has a 9 digit precision after the second:

```
2020-10-20T13:23:03.079208368+02:00
```

But the same command on macOS (same JDK version) only has 6 digits:

```
2020-10-20T13:19:19.299050+02:00
```

JDK 14 on both Linux and macOS also only use 6 digits.

Shouldn't the precision be identical across architectures on the same JDK version?

Comment: Probably because either macOS or your Mac hardware cannot provide that precision. Since Java 9 the precision hasn’t been the same across architectures.