# Java 8 LocalDateTime.now() only giving precision of milliseconds

Tags: java, clock

Is it possible to get microseconds in Java 8? The Java 8 `LocalDateTime` class has a `.getNano()` method which is meant to return `nanoseconds`, but on both Linux(Ubuntu) and OS X (10.11.5) it only returns `milliseconds` (when I ran it it returned `301000000` which equals `301 milliseconds`) and I really need to be able to get `microseconds`.

I know that it is possible to get `nanoseconds` (and therefore get `microseconds` from it) on my computer as the javascript method `process.hrtime()` returns a precise value.

Before anyone starts a precise vs. accurate argument I know that nanoseconds is completely unreliable between threads and shouldn't be used for comparison.

**Edit**:

To be clear the `LocalDateTime` class is part of the Java 8 `java.time` set of classes.

**Update**:

So I realised that Javascript's `process.hrtime` is like Java's `System.nanoTime()` and isn't actually related to the wall clock, it's time since some arbitrary value which are different between the two languages.

New question: Is there a way that I can parse clock time from these values? Ie. If I get `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`, and compare that to another set of those values could I get the actual time of the second set of values?

My problem is that I need to do logging using both Java and Javascript and they need to have a consistent microsecond field across both of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472569/any-new-method-to-get-current-time-with-accuracy-in-microseconds-in-java-now

Comment: That post was originally from 2009 and the updated answer is the solution that I am having issues with. I am looking for something different.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now-- is the best available method for the most precise timestamps.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## tl;dr

> Is it possible to get microseconds in Java 8?

No, not in Java 8. Use Java 9 or later.

```
Instant.now()  // Returns a value in microseconds in Java 9 and later, but is restricted to mere milliseconds in Java 8.
```

This refers to implementations of Java based on the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) open-source code. Others may vary.

## Java 9 and later

The implementations of Java 9 based on OpenJDK have a [fresh implementation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730) of [`java.time.Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) capable of capturing the current moment in resolution finer than milliseconds (*three* digits of decimal fraction).

The actual resolution depends on the limits of your host computer hardware clock. On macOS Sierra with Oracle Java 9.0.4, I am getting current moment with microseconds (*six* digits of decimal fraction).

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2018-03-09T21:03:33.831515Z

## Java 8

The java.time classes were new in Java 8. These classes are defined to carry nanoseconds (*nine* digits of decimal fraction). But capturing the current moment was limited to only [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) in Java 8, and enhanced in Java 9 to capture the current moment in finer [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

> 2018-03-09T21:03:33.831Z

## Other issues

### `System.currentTimeMillis()`

> If I get System.currentTimeMillis() and System.nanoTime()

No need to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` ever again. Instead use `java.time.Instant` for a moment in UTC with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds.

If you really need a count of milliseconds from the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z, ask the `Instant` object. Be aware of data loss, as you would be ignoring any microseconds or nanoseconds present in the `Instant`.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.now().toEpochMilli() ;
```

> Is there a way that I can parse clock time from these values?

Yes, you can convert a count of milliseconds since epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00Z to a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

### `System.nanoTime()`

As for `System.nanoTime()`, that is intended for tracking elapsed time, such as benchmarking your code’ performance. Calling `System.nanoTime()` does *not* tell you anything about the current date-time.

This value is a count of nanoseconds since some undocumented origin point in time. In practice, I have seen the number appear to track time since the JVM launched, but this behavior is not documented and so you should not rely upon it.

### `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment

> My problem is that I need to do logging using both Java and Javascript and they need to have a consistent microsecond field across both of them.

Firstly, for logging you should *not* be using `LocalDateTime` class. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, a `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` is an idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours. Use `LocalDateTime` only if the zone/offset is unknown (not a good situation), or if this represents something like "Christmas Day starts on first moment of Decemeber 25, 2018", where Christmas starts at different moments for different regions around the globe, starting first in the far East (Pacific), and moving westward midnight after successive midnight.

For logging you should be using UTC. In Java, that would be the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class, always in UTC by definition. Just call `Instant.now()`.

When serializing to text such as for logging, always use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. You saw examples above in this Answer.

See another Question, [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

#### ISO 8601

In ISO 8601, the decimal fraction of a second can have any number of digits. So you really should not care about whether the logged event was recorded in milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-03-09T21:03:33.123456789Z" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-03-09T21:03:33.123456Z" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-03-09T21:03:33.123Z" ) ;
```

#### Truncate

If you *really* believe you need uniform resolution, you can [truncate a `Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ) ; // Strip away any microseconds or nanoseconds.
```

#### Don't worry about resolution

> My problem is that I need to do logging using both Java and Javascript and they need to have a consistent microsecond field across both of them.

Firstly, I doubt you really need to care about this. If you use standard ISO 8601 format, and the `Instant` class in Java, you can serialize and re-hydrate a moment successfully in millis, micros, or nanos.

And the ISO 8601 formatted strings will conveniently alphabetize chronologically even if the fractional second resolution varies.

Secondly, if you are trying to track actual moments to microseconds for some reason, you are likely to be disappointed. As of 2018, conventional computer clocks are not reliable in the microsecond range.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: What an answer!

Comment: an excellent and comprehensive answer. Learned a lot!

Comment: For posterity on Android you'll still only get millisecond precision from a Desugared java.time implementation: https://github.com/google/desugar_jdk_libs/blob/be076b13963efbfca6137a56b155398533df53aa/jdk11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Clock.java#L477

Answer (score 4):

The `LocalDate.now()` relies on the `SystemClock::instant()` method, which uses `System.currentTimeMillis()`, so you won't get a more precise resolution with the default clock.

However, you could implement your own high-precision `Clock` and use that in conjunction with LocalDate:

```
LocalDate hpDate = LocalDate.now(microsecondClock);
```

For high-precision you could use the `TickClock` with microsecond ticks:

```
Clock microsecondClock = Clock.tick(Clock.systemUTC(), Duration.ofNanos(1000));
```

or subclass `Clock` and implement your own high precision clock, i.e. by using System.currentTimemillis() and System.nanoTime().

Comment: How would I implement my own clock?

Comment: `class YourClock extends Clock { .... }` ... I assume there are various ways to do this, one could be to run a timer thread, that counts loop iterations between two time measurements of System.currentTimeMillis() form this derive the number of microseconds or nanoseconds in that interval. But keep in mind, the more precise you get, the less accurate it'll be.

Comment: I need to use the micro/nano seconds for sending logs that will also be compared to logs sent from a javascript project, so I need to be able to get a system wide microsecond value.

Answer (score 2):

While your computer is able to report something more precise (but probably not accurate, at least not in wall time) than milliseconds this does not change the fact the Java per default uses a [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) based off of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

You must [provide a more precise `Clock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689213/52162) to get values more precise than ms. That is, [until Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33478391/52162).