# How do I get long(time) in microseconds passed since epoch and then get month and year from the same in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I found this code:

```
long timeStampSeconds = ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.now());
```

but when I converted this back to fetch month and year using the following code, it gives the wrong output.

```
try {
    epochLong = Long.parseLong(epoch);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    //Log exception
    return null;
}

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(epochLong);
String month = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
String year = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
//print month and year
```

Any pointers as to how I can generate this in microseconds and get the month and year back right? Please help.

Comment: what is "the wrong output"?

Comment: I always see epoch getting generated with 3 zeroes at the end, can this be avoided?

Comment: Give and example of: -your input, -what you get, -what you expect to get

Comment: Wrong output is: From epoch like 1574072161043000 expected month is 10 and year 2019 but i get month as 4 and year as 51850 which is absurd

Comment: `setTimeInMillis` and `ChronoUnit.MICROS.between`, maybe millis and micros mismatch... maybe the is another [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MILLIS) that would get a better fit

Comment: I want to generate in micros only. This is the usecase, but how to I get back month and year? Calendar has setTimeInMillis only

Comment: convert micros to milli? hint: it's a division

Comment: the difference between `ChronoUnit.MICROS` and `setTimeInMillis` should ring a bell.

Comment: But the micros also is not generating the precision.. The last 3 digits are zero, first of all how do I get the last 3 precision bits also.. and then how do I set? (If I divide I loose them again)

Comment: What about `ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.now())`? **MILLIS**... I just used that and it gave me the correct month and year... By the way, I was using `java.time` only.

Comment: Thanks but My requirement is that I need to first convert to micros only

Comment: Please don't use `Calendar` it is legacy now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 LocalDateTime.now() only giving precision of milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586311/java-8-localdatetime-now-only-giving-precision-of-milliseconds)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `java.time` from Java-8 you can use :

```
long timeStampSeconds = ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.now());
```

to back you can convert this to an instant, then the instant to the `ZoneDateTime`

```
Instant inst = Instant.EPOCH.plus(timeStampSeconds, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toChronoUnit());
ZonedDateTime zdt = inst.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
```

Then you can get the month, year, day, hour, ...

```
Month month = zdt.getMonth();
int year = zdt.getYear();
```

**Outputs**

```
MICROS:       1574073141066090
ZoneDateTime: 2019-11-18T11:32:21.066090+01:00[Europe/Paris]
```

Comment: But here again timeStampSeconds will not give the precision digits.

Comment: How did u get this: 1574073141066090?
ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.now()) always generates last 3 digits 0.

Comment: I need to know what exactly u printed for MICROS?

Comment: @SamayraGoyal I print `System.out.println(timeStampSeconds);`

Comment: @YCF_L thanks but I always get last 3 digits as 000 when I print , donno how u got 090.

Comment: @SamayraGoyal for me I don't get always Zeros in the end, for example now `1574073452060455`

Comment: @SamayraGoyal check this [ideon demo](https://www.ideone.com/vJzDyY)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202560/discussion-between-samayra-goyal-and-ycf-l).

Comment: @SamayraGoyal I guess it is a problem with jdk version, I passed with this problem there are few months, and if I can remember the problem come from toString which erase the last part and set it as 000, I'm not sure, but I will search for it and let you in touch

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730 • [Java 8 LocalDateTime.now() only giving precision of milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39586311/2711488)…

Comment: Thank you @Holger for sharing this links, so as I guessed there are problem with jdk version of the OP

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the platform and the Java version.

On my Mac example `timeStampSeconds` values from your code include

- using jdk-1.8.0_121: 1574193249064000 and 1574193338130000; so always ending in 000
- using jdk-9.0.4: 1574193430428678 and 1574193438362321; so usually not ending in 000.

On Java 8 the `now` methods of the java.time classes haven’t got any finer granularity than millisenods, so the microsecond of millisecond will always be 000. On Java 9 a finer granularity is available if the platform supports it, which may not be the case for all platforms.

So if you’re getting 000 always, the solution is to upgrade at least to Java 9 and run your Java program on a computer that supports microsecond precision.

### Don’t use Calendar

The `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Also it never supports any unit finer than milliseconds. To convert your microsecond value back to a date and time object, use for example:

```
    long timeStampSeconds = 1_574_193_438_362_321L;
    Instant convertedBack = Instant.EPOCH.plus(timeStampSeconds, ChronoUnit.MICROS);
    System.out.println(convertedBack);
```

> 2019-11-19T19:57:18.362321Z

You will notice that the full microsecond precision is preserved. YCF_L in another answer has already shown how to get the year and month values.