# Read db2 timestamp in java in 26 character format? Last characters of milliseconds are missing

Tags: java, sql, timestamp, db2

I'm trying to retrieve a field from my database table.

> column name - create_timestamp
>
> Data type of my DB2 column - Timestamp
>
> Format in DB2 - yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS

I'm able to view data in this format in DB visualizer

I'm reading this value from resultset in java using

```
bean.setCreateTimestamp(rs.getTimestamp(create_timestamp));
```

`createTimestamp` field of bean is of `java.sql.Timestamp` type

When I print using `bean.getCreateTimestamp()`, the last three numbers of 
Actual DB2 value: `2016-01-30 11:43:06.006000` milliseconds are missing.

yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS is the format printed

Sysout value: From bean>>2016-01-30 11:43:06.006

What should I do to get the complete timestamp?
I need this data to create filenames for report generation.

Comment: Show us the code you are using to print the timestamp in Java.  I'm not convinced that the precision has actually been lost.

Comment: What version of DB2? What version of Java? I know that on IBM i, certain methods of retrieving the timestamp only returns milliseconds (first three decimal positions), and microseconds (positions 4-6) are returned as 0.

Comment: It appears from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472569/any-new-method-to-get-current-time-with-accuracy-in-microseconds-in-java-now that even up to Java 8, the Java Clock class is only accurate up to milliseconds (3 digits). so what is in the DB? What is loading the DB field. Even though the field can hold microseconds, the process loading the field must be able to provide the microseconds.DB2 for i (at least at v7.1+) can provide microseconds using now(), CURRENT_TIME, or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I can't test any earlier right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is quite confusing, not sure if you are capturing the current time in Java or in your database. Either way, you are using a troublesome old date-time class (`java.sql.Timestamp`) that is now legacy, supplanted by *java.time* classes.

The *java.time* classes use a resolution of nanoseconds, for up to *nine* decimal digits of a fractional second. **In any version of Java, you can *carry* a nanosecond value.** However, *capturing* the current moment is a different story.

- **Java 8**
  Capturing the current moment in Java 8 is limited to milliseconds, for three digits of resolution.
- **Java 9 and later**
  Capturing the current moment in Java 9 uses a [fresh implementation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730) of [`java.time.Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) with finer resolution, depending on the limits of your host computer hardware of course.

On macOS Sierra running on a MacBook Pro with Intel i7 chip using Oracle Java 9.0.4, I am capturing the current moment in microseconds for six digits of decimal fraction.

```
Instant.now()
```

> 2018-03-09T21:03:33.831515Z

With a JDBC driver supporting JDBC 4.2 and later, you should be able to directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. No need to ever use `java.sql.Timestamp` again.

If your DB2 column lacks time zone or offset-from-UTC info, use `LocalDateTime` class in Java.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

If your database column is in UTC, use `Instant` class.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).