# Neo4j getting the system's datetime containing micro or nano seconds with cypher

Tags: java, datetime, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In neo4j I know how to get the current datetime as in now() with milliseconds precision, however I would like to be able to store microseconds or nanoseconds. Is there a way to achieve this via apoc, or adjusting my system time. I was reading about the 'limitations' of java Date and Calendar only storing .SSS ?

```
CREATE (l:LogEvent{
        eventID : 'I01'
        , dt : System.nanoTime({timezone:'UTC'})
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current time in microseconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, hoping somebody would have found a workaround or pointed to something I had overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [temporal instants](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-accessing-components-temporal-instants) `DateTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `Time`, and `LocalTime` support the `microsecond` and `nanosecond` fields. Those fields can be set when using the appropriate temporal function to create an instant.

For example:

```
RETURN datetime({year:1984, month:11, day:11, hour:12, minute:31, second:14, nanosecond: 645876123, timezone:'Europe/Stockholm'})
```

In addition, if you have an epoch time with microsecond (or nanosecond) precision that you want to store, just break it down into 2 parts: its epoch seconds, and the remaining microseconds (or nanoseconds). With those 2 parts, you can create a `DateTime` as illustrated here (assuming `secs`, `micros`, and `nanos` are passed as [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)s):

```
RETURN datetime({epochSeconds: $secs, microsecond: $micros})
```

or

```
RETURN datetime({epochSeconds: $secs, nanosecond: $nanos})
```