# How to get the current time of microsecond accuracy

Tags: java, java-8

How to get the current time of microsecond accuracy in Java 8?

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.getDefault())
                                                       .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(dateTimeFormatter));
```

Java 9 or above can, how to do Java 8?

Comment: String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current time in microseconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java)

Comment: What's the Java 9 way you mentioned? Can you show us what you mean (code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Java 9+ captures current moment in microseconds, while Java 8 captures in mere milliseconds.

```
ZonedDateTime
.now()  // Uses JVM’s current default time zone.
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ) // Uses JVM’s current default locale.
)
```

## `ZonedDateTime.now`

I cannot image a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do. That class cannot represent a moment as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset. Use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;
```

In Java 8, the moment was captured with a resolution of milliseconds. In Java 9+, microseconds. In all versions, the *java.time* types are capable of representing nanoseconds, but conventional computers lack the hardware clocks to accurately capture current moment in nanos.

Generate text representing that object’s value in standard ISO 8601 format extended by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

Generate localized text.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.getDefault()
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```